# AndroidStudio : Migrate project in "Gradle"

Tags: android, mobile

I'm a french student, so i'm sorry for my english..

I am working on an application on Android with AndroidStudio.
I received some source code by someone. But when i want to open the project which i received, AndroidStudio tells me

> "This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that
>   you migrate to using the Gradle build system."

And i have more information here :

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/intellij_to_gradle

But i don't understand what i have to make..

Thank you for your answers !

EDIT : I try to import the folder with Android Studio, but there is an error :

> Failed to sync Gradle project 'name_project'
>
> Failed to find target with hash string 'android-16' in ...

Answer (score 1):

Android studio give you error whenever you try to open any non-gradle based project and failed find gradle configuration/files in your project.

If it's eclipse project then you just need to import it into the Android studio and it would take care of most of required things.

From documentation: [Migrating from Eclipse projects to Android studio](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects)

> Importing the Eclipse project directly into Studio. This is the
>   preferred approach, and has numerous advantages:
>
> - It will detect many source libraries (such as ActionBarSherlock) and binary libraries (e.g. guava.jar), and will replace these with
>     maven dependencies instead, which means you no longer have to maintain
>     the libraries manually
> - It will rewrite the project using the new canonical Android Gradle project structure, which supports instrumentation tests in the same
>     project as the tested code, flavor and build type specific resources,
>     etc

Answer (score 0):

You do not have nothing to worry about. When Ever you try to open the Eclipse project into a Android studio , this is a question that is asked by Android studio, to move up to gradle , as Android studio uses Gradle to build the applications.

So you just need to import that project into the android studio, android studio would take care of code itself. If that eclipse project was using some kind of library , then let the android studio download the library and add them in the dependency

well you can do this manually.

Comment: Like i say to Paresh, it doesn't work..

It display "Failed to sync Gradle project 'name_project' Failed to find target with hash string 'android-16' in path